# How do i use refetchOnReconnect properly for a builder.mutation endpoint in @redux/toolkit/query?

Tags: typescript, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit

Redux refetchOnReconnect option not working event after I called the setupListener(store.dispatch) in my redux store.tsx file, And setting refetchOnReconnect=true to the endpoint hook call.

**store.tsx file**

```
'use client';

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";


import { apiSlice } from "../features/api/apiSlice";

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage
}

const allReducers = {
  [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer
};

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: allReducers,
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch)

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

**apiSlice.tsx file**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

let url = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TS_SERVER_URL : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_APP_BASE_URL;

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: url,
  }),
  tagTypes: [
    "Product",
  ],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});

export default apiSlice;
```

**productApi.tsx file**

```
import apiSlice from "../api/apiSlice";

const productApi = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    // get all products
    displayProducts: builder.query({
      query: ({ page, limit }) => ({
        url: `api/product/all?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`,
        method: "GET",
      }),
      providesTags: ["Product"],
      refetchOnReconnect: true,
    }),
    // get product
    displayProduct: builder.query({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `api/product/${id}`,
        method: "GET",
      }),
      providesTags: ["Product"],
      refetchOnReconnect: true,
      keepUnusedDataFor: 1,
      retries: 3, // Set the number of retry attempts
      retryOnUnmountOrReconnect: true
      // async onQueryStarted(_, {dispatch, queryFulfilled}){
      //   dispatch(apiSlice.internalActions.onOnline(refetchOnReconnect))
      // }
    }),

  }),
  overrideExisting: module.hot?.status() === "apply",
});

export const {
  useDisplayProductsQuery,
  useDisplayProductQuery,
} = productApi;
```

The result i expect to get is a refetch of data from any of endpoints in productApi.tsx when ever there's a network connection. for example when action {type: '__rtkq/online', payload: undefined} is dispatched, then  action api/executeQuery/pending gets called.

Answer (score 0):

- `retryOnUnmountOrReconnect` is not an option in RTK Query, but it seems like something that ChatGPT would hallucinate?
- Same for `retries`. (You need to wrap your baseQuery for that)
- `refetchOnReconnect` cannot be used inside of endpoint definitions, just for the full api.
- And mutations will never automatically refetch, because the point of a mutation is to change something on the server - and you don't automatically do that.

Is there any chance you can consider using TypeScript? You are using a lot of wrong options in the wrong places, and TypeScript would save you a *lot* of time and frustration here by immediately telling you what can and can not go where.